# What is the $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

How am I supposed to know this equals 1?

I could sub $x= \frac{1}{n}$ to get

$$\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} $$

Using L'Hopital's I'd get:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{1} $$

But, $\cos(x)$ just cycles between $-1$ and $1$, so how can the limit be $1$ ?

Comment: You should replace $\infty$ with $0$.

Comment: Your second displayed line is wrong. If $x=\frac1n$, then $x\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: For the record: L'Hopital here is overkill (and circular). You use the fact that $\sin^\prime=\cos$ to apply L'Hopital, but then you have by definition $\sin^\prime(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x - \sin 0}{x-0} = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ already. So applying L'Hopital's rule here is tantamount to opening a can with a jackhammer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:**

If $x=\frac{1}{n}$, then as $n\to\infty$, $x\to 0^+$

So the limit becomes:
$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$